# Jetpack Compose Floating Action Button is not showing up

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet dialog. For the dialog, I'm using `ModalBottomSheetDialog` from the `Accompanist` navigation library. In the dialog which is a composable fun that named `PlatformsScreen`, I have a `LazyColumn` with items that has `RadioButton`. Whenever any of the radio buttons is selected I'm adding the selected item into the `selectedPlatforms` which is a `mutableList`:

```
@Composable
fun PlatformsScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel: PlatformsScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    // this is the platforms that I fetch from network
    val platforms = viewModel.platforms.observeAsState()

    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    //this is the platforms that I selected from the platforms list
    val selectedPlatforms by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(mutableListOf<Platform>())
    }
    
    DefaultScreenUI(toolbar = {
        BottomSheetDialogToolbar(title = "Platforms")
    },
        floatingActionButton = {
            //This is not working
            AnimatedVisibility(visible = selectedPlatforms.size > 0,
                enter = expandVertically(),
                exit = shrinkVertically())
            {
                ApplyFilterFab()
            }
        }
    ) {

        when (platforms.value) {
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                LoadingItem()
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                ErrorItem(message = platforms.value!!.error!!,
                    onRetryClick = viewModel::setRefresh)
            }
            is Resource.Success -> {
                if (platforms.value!!.data!!.isNotEmpty()) {
                    LazyColumn(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(), state = listState) {
                        items(count = platforms.value!!.data!!.size) {
                            //platform item
                            PlatformItem(
                                platform = platforms.value!!.data!![it],
                            ) { platform, selected ->
                                Timber.d(selectedPlatforms.size.toString())
                                if (!selected) {
                                    selectedPlatforms.remove(platform)
                                } else {
                                    selectedPlatforms.add(platform)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    //empty view
                }
            }

        }
}
}
```

The `DefaultScreenUI` is also a composable fun with `Scaffold` :

```
@Composable
fun DefaultScreenUI(
    toolbar: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
    floatingActionButton: (@Composable () -> Unit)? = null,
    fabPos: FabPosition = FabPosition.End,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        topBar = { toolbar?.invoke() },
        floatingActionButton = { floatingActionButton?.invoke() },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = fabPos) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary)) {
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is also my `PlatformItem` composable:

```
@Composable
fun PlatformItem(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    platform: Platform,
    onItemSelected: (Platform,Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    var selected by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Row(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(40.dp)
        .clickable {
            selected = !selected
            onItemSelected(platform,selected)
        },
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(start = dimensionResource(id = R.dimen.dimen_8)),
            text = platform.name!!,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1,
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)

        RadioButton(selected = selected, onClick = {
            selected = !selected
            onItemSelected(platform,selected)
        })

    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is whenever any of the items in the list has selected which means `selectedPlatforms.size > 0` I want to show the `FloatingActionButton` in the dialog and hide the button if `selectedPlatforms` is empty. Here is the result:

[image]

As you can see it is not showing up. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug and I've [reported it](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224005027).

Until it's fixed, the easiest solution at the moment is to switch to `scaleIn` / `scaleOut` transitions, they work fine.

An other option is putting `AnimatedVisibility` is a `Box` of FAB static size, which is `56.dp`, in this case other transitions work fine, except the clipped shadow. The shadow can be disabled by zeroing the `elevation` parameter, which is not the best solution either.

Comment: Thanks wrapping the FAB in a box works!

Answer (score 1):

This is regarding a fix for FAB (Floating Action Button). The issue lies in the default animation "expandIn" of AnimatedVisibility, which includes "ChangeSize" and has a default value of IntSize(0, 0). When the size is set to zero, the FAB does not appear during recomposition. If this bug occurs in production, you can address it by following the steps below.

```
  AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = isShowButtonAdd,
            enter = expandIn { IntSize(width = 1, height = 1) }
             ) {
             FloatingActionButton(onClick = { }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.Add, contentDescription = "Add")
            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Composable
fun FabButton (){
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(),
        floatingActionButton  = {
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                text = { Text("Add Button") },
                icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Add,"")},
                onClick = { },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.4f)
                    .fillMaxHeight(0.075f),
                shape = AbsoluteRoundedCornerShape(50),
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary
                )
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = false,
        content = {}
    )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).